# Jquery offset method for all elements in an array rather than just the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, offset

I have few divs on a page with same class. I want to use jquery offset method to find offsets for all these divs.

> $('div').offset()

returns me the offset for the first div.

But, if I want offset for all the divs, is there some way to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to iterate on the divs:

```
$('div').each(function() {
     console.log($(this).offset());
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Building on @dystroy's answer:

```
var offsetCollection = new Array();
$('div').each(function() {
     offsetCollection.push(
       $(this).offset(), $(this).index()
     );
});
```

You can then:

```
offsetCollection[0][0]; //div 1, offset
offsetCollection[0][1]; //div 1, elementIndex
```